# Unloading viewControllers from UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I got a UIPageViewController where I add other viewControllers. Those ViewControllers are in the array `viewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` I add viewControllers on this array like this:

```
        [viewControllersArray addObject: infoViewController];
```

After the viewControllers are added on my array:

```
NSArray *initialViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:0], nil];
[self setViewControllers:initialViewControllers
               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                animated:YES
              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                  NSLog(@"call back success");}];
```

This above code is all done in the viewDidLoad from my UIPageViewController.

For loading this array I got those functions form `<UIPageViewControllerDataSource>`
which I use like this:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewControllersArray containsObject:viewController]) {
        NSInteger index = [viewControllersArray indexOfObject:viewController];
        if (index < [viewControllersArray count] && index > 0) {
            return [viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:(index - 1)];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewControllersArray containsObject:viewController]) {
        NSInteger index = [viewControllersArray indexOfObject:viewController];
        if (index < [viewControllersArray count] - 1) {
            return [viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:(index + 1)];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Now what the problem is, is that when you swipe, the next viewcontrollers gets load, etc. But they don't get unloaded. So I'm searching for a way to unload the viewcontrollers that you already passed to save memory, and when you swipe back they will get reloaded.

Answer (score 3):

your problem is that you hold on to your view controllers in the `viewControllersArray`. The array holds a strong reference to each object that you add to it. The easiest way to save memory is to just create the requested view controller on the fly in both the `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` and the `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:` data source methods. That way, only the page view controller will have a strong reference to the view controller and will release (dealloc) it once it is moved off-screen.

If it's too expensive to create them on-the-fly, you might consider just keeping 3 view controllers in the array: the one currently displayed and the one to the immediate left and the immediate right.

Example:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(MyGreatViewController *)vc
{
    NSUInteger index = vc.position - 1; //custom property on your VC
    if (index > 0) {
      return [[MyGreatViewController alloc] initWithPosition:index];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc
       viewControllerBeforeViewController:(MyGreatViewController *)vc
{
    NSUInteger index = vc.position + 1; //custom property on your VC
    if (index <= MAX_POSITION) {
      return [[MyGreatViewController alloc] initWithPosition:index];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: What do you mean by "create them on the fly"? I add all my viewcontrollers using a for-loop in the viewDidLoad method for the class and then I add them to the array.

Comment: View my edited answer. You simply alloc-init the view controller _once you need it_ and not earlier. Don't add them all to an array ahead of time: The user might never swipe that far and might never need to look at that view controller. Only create it in the data source methods once you really need it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, I've made a tiny sample project: http://www.2shared.com/file/rbsxMLgz/pageScroll.html to show you how I add all those viewControllers. Using this method is OK, but when you swipe to the right, next pages get added but the ones before don't get removed from the UIPageViewController and stay in memory

Comment: Just don't add them to an array. As long as all your view controllers are in an array, their memory will never get released until you remove them from the array. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not unload View Controller. If memory is low, controllers unload their views. In code, use `-(void)viewDidUnload` and `-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` (iOS 6) to free your resources. When UIPageViewController will show some page, controller recreate unloaded view and call `-(void)viewDidLoad` (if you customize your controllers manually).

Comment: I've already implemented didReceiveMemoryWarning, and set the view to nil but this doesn't get much memory freed

Comment: Memory completely freed when you leave @autoreleasepool blocks, if you have only one (in main.m), then memory freed when program closes. You can add your own autorelease blocks in code, where you allocate too much memory